# odoo issue tracking doesn't show up after installation / Version 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, issue-tracking

I've installed the module Issue Tracking on my Odoo 10.0-20170705 (Community Edition). 
There isn't any change at the menus or settings. I can't find the module. The App-overview says, it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I did found the cause. I wasn't logged in as an administrator

Comment: Issue Tracking access rights are handled by the groups "Project User" and "Project Manager". So if you want to see something changed, your logged in user should be in one of these groups. You don't need to be the administrator.